# SQL check if Int is null select NVarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if an INT is null, and if so select a different name for the value. But I keep getting a

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NAME' to data type int

I want something like..

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(ForeignID, SecondName), FirstName) AS NAME,
```

Simply, if null select the second name, otherwise if it has a value, select the first

Comment: What database are you using?  Does it have `COALESCE()` ?

Comment: @JeffUK MSSMS, I think it does have that

Comment: So what is `ForeignID` here? Preumably that's an int; explicitely cast that as varchar.

Comment: `case when ForeignID is not null then FirstName else SecondName end`

Comment: I'm not sure what you think it does but it looks like you think `NULLIF` means "If the first parameter is `NULL` return the second parameter" that's `ISNULL`. `NULLIF` returns `NULL` if the first and second parameters are equal. So, for example, `NULLIF(1,1)` would return `NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` *expression* instead:

```
case when ForeignID is not null then FirstName else SecondName end
```